# How to create a lucene query

Tags: lucene

I am writing some code the need to include all the words in the search string, eg "Apple is red". I am currently using MultiFieldQueryParser, but the search query will be (title:"apple ? red" body:"apple ? red"). I want the query looks exactly what the string should be. "apple ? red" should become "apple is red". How to I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks correct.  The question mark in the output indicates a position increment, it doesn't indicate an actual term in the query.

The word "is" is removed from the query and the index by `StandardAnalyzer`, since it is a stop word in the default stop word set.  `StopFilter` removes those terms, but increments the position to indicate where the term was removed to enable closer matching with phrase queries.

Unless you see an issue with the *results* of the query, there appears to be nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Are there anyway to remove the stop word set from it?

Comment: [Yes](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html#StandardAnalyzer(org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet))

Comment: thanks, I looked at the java doc, and put an new reader in the analyzer constructor, it works now.